# Crossfading transitions effect not using images

Tags: jquery, css-transitions, transition, fadein, cross-fade

I am trying to create a testimonial section for a project I'm working on. Ideally I'd like each testimonial to fade out and then have the next one fade in and so on. Unfortunately after a bit of Googling, I can't find any examples or tutorials that don't involve transitioning anything other than just an image to the next image.

Any links to code snippets, plugins, tutorials, or just pure advice on how to complete this would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the JQuery library http://jquery.com/

Then take advantage of its awesome functionality http://api.jquery.com/?s=fade

Wrap a DIV around the testimonial section and apply the fade or animation to it. If you want a plugin then perhaps you want to google "jQuery Plugin testimonials etc." or "jQuery Carousel". It will get you close to what you want